# React components are laying on top of each other instead of being laying from top to bottom

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have these two components in which the first is laying on top of the next component in the App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Banner />
      <AboutUs />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Below is the code for the Banner

```
function Banner() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative">
        <img
          className="w-full h-80 md:h-96 object-cover object-center absolute brightness-75"
          alt="banner"
          src={bannerImage}
        />
        <div className="absolute bg-white top-2 left-2 md:top-5 md:left-5 bg-transparent border border-solid cursor-default hover:scale-110 transition-all duration-300 hover:opacity-30 border-white">
          <h1 className=" text-sm md:text-xl font-semibold md:px-5 md:py-2 px-2 py-1">
            FAMILY LAW
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 translate-y-12 md:translate-y-28">
          <h2 className="text-center font-medium text-white">
            We Always <span className=" text-[#E5912E]">care</span> about our
            client <span className=" text-[#E5912E]">satisfaction</span>
          </h2>
          <br />
          <p className="font-bold text-xl md:text-4xl text-center text-white transition-all duration-300">
            <span className=" text-[#E5912E]">JUSTICE</span> FOR ALL
          </p>
          <br />
          <div className="flex space-x-2 justify-center">
            <div className="bg-[#E5912E] px-3 py-1 rounded-sm cursor-pointer">
              <h2 className="text-white text-sm text-center">Know More</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="bg-transparent border border-solid px-4 py-1 rounded-sm cursor-pointer">
              <h2 className="text-white text-sm text-center">About us</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The `AboutUs` components contains just a single image but it seems the Banner component is lying on top of the image

Comment: Chances are you shouldn't be using absolute positioning. It's troublesome as it takes elements out of the document flow. Don't use it unless you fully understand that implication.

Comment: Since this is really a CSS question. next time just post rendered HTML and the Tailwind library in a snippet demo. Then we can actually see the problem and propose clear solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When you use absolute positioning, it pulls the element out of the document flow.  That means that everything that follows the absolute positioned element in the source order will behave as though that element isn't there.  In your case, that means that the Banner component has a resulting height of 0 and the page content begins at the top of the screen (behind where the Banner displays).

So to fix things, instead of setting the height and width on the absolutely positioned img in your Banner component, place the height and width on the wrapping relatively positioned div.  Then set your absolutely positioned img to fill the height and width of the div fully.

To make things easier to center the text content on the image, use CSS grid and `place-content: center` to center the text and buttons both vertically and horizontally.

#### Working snippet below

```js
function AboutUs() {
  return (
    <main className="p-4">
      <h1 className="font-bold text-4xl">About Us</h1>
    </main>
  )
}


function Banner() {
  return (
    <div className="relative h-80 md:h-96">
      <img
        className="object-cover object-center absolute h-full w-full inset-0 brightness-75"
        alt="banner"
        src="https://picsum.photos/id/23/600"
      />
      <div className="absolute bg-white top-2 left-2 md:top-5 md:left-5 bg-transparent border border-solid cursor-default hover:scale-110 transition-all duration-300 hover:opacity-30 border-white">
        <h1 className=" text-sm md:text-xl font-semibold md:px-5 md:py-2 px-2 py-1">
          FAMILY LAW
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="absolute inset-0 grid place-content-center text-center">
        <h2 className="text-center font-medium text-white">
          We Always <span className=" text-[#E5912E]">care</span> about our
          client <span className=" text-[#E5912E]">satisfaction</span>
        </h2>
        <br />
        <p className="font-bold text-xl md:text-4xl text-center text-white transition-all duration-300">
          <span className=" text-[#E5912E]">JUSTICE</span> FOR ALL
        </p>
        <br />
        <div className="flex space-x-2 justify-center">
          <div className="bg-[#E5912E] px-3 py-1 rounded-sm cursor-pointer">
            <h2 className="text-white text-sm text-center">Know More</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="bg-transparent border border-solid px-4 py-1 rounded-sm cursor-pointer">
            <h2 className="text-white text-sm text-center">About us</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}



function App(){ 
  return (
    <div>
      <Banner />
      <AboutUs />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```